# .net core how server identify request from client(browser) after authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In .net core web application, I am using following code to authenticate users.

```
 services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(this.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ApiScope") })
                .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

Now my question is after authentication, where server and browser keeps identity of that user?

After authentication, next time when request comes from client(browser) then how server knows that user?

Comment: Cookie. You can check the requests sending to the backend after the user has signed in, and you will find in the request header there's `cookie: .AspNetCore.Cookies=` inside it. I think this is the reason for not need to signed in again.

Comment: so exactly what is going to be store at client and how server validate that when request comes?